# Piwik dashboard into website integration

Tags: php, iframe, integration, matomo, web-statistics

What I want to do is, to integrate whole [piwik](http://piwik.org/) dashboard into website admin panel so that only admins could see stats.

Using following code.

```
<iframe src="<url to piwik folder>/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&moduleToWidgetize=Dashboard&actionToWidgetize=index&idSite=1&period=week&date=yesterday" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

But piwik gives me following screen

```
The requested website idSite is not found in the request, or is invalid. Please check that you are logged in Piwik and have permission to access the specified website.

Go to Piwik
Login
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not authenticated to piwik. If you login into piwik the iframe should work for you.
If you want anonymous users to view the dashboard you have to give them the view permission in the Users Management section.

This is also mentioned on the Widgets startpage. "Widget authentication"